# Modal backdrop doesn't appear

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When I am trying to open multiple modals, one after another, the backdrop doesn't appear after the last one is open. The situation as it seems is that the backdrop is appearing before the first modal that was opened. What could be the cause for this issue?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals read `Multiple open modals not supported` and if want to open multiple modals then `requires custom code.` if you are opening modal with jQuery or default bootstrap method, can help you to solve the problem but angular is not my playground :)

Comment: The angular-ui-bootstrap library supports multiple open modals.